# Can't View VBA Form

Tags: vba, excel, userform

So I created a form, and have been using it for a while.

All of a sudden today it stopped working. Other forms load and can be viewed but not this one.

The weirdest part is that the controls still respond!

So I can't actually see the form but I can still interact with it. (only using keyboard no mouse clicks are responding) I know the form is enabled. But I simply can't see it! I have restarted excel, and the whole computer.

I even completely removed all code in the userform to see if I could get the blank shell to load, and while I can tell it loads (it disables everything in excel until I use Alt+F4) it still won't be visible. I have checked the Enabled, All Colors, Captiuon, Width, Height, Top, Left, StartUpPostion, SpecialEffect, Zoom, DrawBuffer properties and everything is fine.

I have also Exported and reimported it and still simply nothing. Also tried importing it into another Workbook, nothing. I at my wits end (not that it's very far to reach!)

Also, I can still see the userform in the designer I can still edit it, I get NO errors. This happens not only when calling the form in code, but even when running it right from the designer.

Any one ever have this issue? Any ideas or solutions?

Comment: @PortlandRunner I tried that, I tried that on the load event, the Initialize event, I also added a msgbox to this event, the msgbox pops up, but no form. Also tried it in a button click. There are no errors, not even handled or hidden ones. But the Show shouldn't be needed when launches the form by itself from the designer anyways.

Comment: I'm curious. What version are you using? Can you upload the file somewhere so I can download it? I want to inspect what's happening to the userform.

Comment: If you reduce the size of the application window, can you see the form behind it? I've had this happen with Excel's built-in dialogs before (due to a COM add-in in Outlook bizarrely).

Comment: @Rory No, I tried that as well, I tried bring to front in windows on the form and everything. I ended up remaking the form and it works without any issues, didn't change a thing, I am at a loss.

Comment: Can you post the properties of your form?

Comment: when your form shows (or initializes), do you set something to reduce the excel window to windows taskbar ? (i do this when i want some room sometimes)... But i noticed, that if i manualy clic on the exel windows '_' (reduce) button, the form disapears as well...

Comment: also try disable `Userform_Initailize` AND `Userform_Activate` with a simple `exit sub` at its begin.

Comment: @PatrickLepelletier I have solved this already and added an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being the Top and left properties. While I did check them, they way I checked them was not accurate; I still have no idea why, but I think it defiantly has something to do with dual monitor setup.

The way I tested double checked the forms top and left properties was by creating a new form and adding a button on the button click event I had a msgbox show the top and left properties of the form at time of clicking.

I then moved the new form to where I wanted the form that woudn't show to be and clicked the button; I then set these values to the form that wouldn't show.

I tested this location and made sure to match the properties with the values I wanted multiple times and it didn't work.

For some reason the values needed where about 1000 digits off (instead of 250 I needed to use 1250) even though I had set the form right where I wanted the new one to be and made sure to save the properties when they matched what I wanted

Comment: i had similar problem, because my VBA editor window was on the 2nd monitor, and it didn't show my Form on the same monitor as the excel application but on the VBE's monitor.